# WORD VBA sorting words in paragraphs

Tags: vba, ms-word

Hi guys i am hoping that you guys can point me in the right direction. I am trying to come up with a macro that will sort words in ascending order for each paragraph. To make it clear i am giving an example below:

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. <---- given
brown dog fox jumps lazy over quick the the <---- the output
```

The output should show below the para/s right at the end of the docu already sorted. Any help or advice as to how i can go about it using Ranges, pls let me know. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this code might point you in the right direction.

Notice you'll need to add somewhere the sorted array (as of now, it's only sorting the array values).

I used the sorting function available [HERE](http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.asp?ID=3197).

Hope it helps!

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text

Sub orderParagraph()

    Dim oParagraph As Word.Paragraph
    Dim vParagraphText As Variant

    For Each oParagraph In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs

        If Len(Trim(oParagraph.Range.Text)) > 0 Then

            vParagraphText = oParagraph.Range.Text
            vParagraphText = Split(vParagraphText, " ")
            SortArray vParagraphText

        End If

    Next oParagraph


End Sub

Private Function SortArray(ByRef TheArray As Variant)

    Dim x As Integer
    Dim bSorted As Boolean
    Dim sTempText As String

    bSorted = False

    Do While Not bSorted

        bSorted = True

        For x = 0 To UBound(TheArray) - 1

            If TheArray(x) > TheArray(x + 1) Then

                sTempText = TheArray(x + 1)
                TheArray(x + 1) = TheArray(x)
                TheArray(x) = sTempText
                bSorted = False

            End If

        Next x

    Loop

End Function
```

Comment: Real big help indeed! Thanks man! Is it not possible to store the values in an array, display them at the bottom in list style and then apply the built-in sorting method of word? eg. expression.Sort(parameters)

Comment: Also how can this be done without including the periods, commas, etc. it should just extract the text. Any help?

Comment: @decrementor, simply add these two lines right before split command:             vParagraphText = Replace(vParagraphText, ".", "")
            vParagraphText = Replace(vParagraphText, ",", "")